# how to extract "chi square for each group:" values from lavaan when using known groups

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I want to extract the individual group chi square values from `lavaan` output that is provided when conducting multiple, known group sem models. Only the total chi square is provided as a `fitMeasure`, and the chi square values are not treated as individual estimates in `parameterEstimates`. There doesn't appear to be any other automated method for extracting this information.

I have been able to use the `capture.output()` function, and from there I can find the heading for the chi square values, and count the number of lines of values based on the number of groups + 1. Then I can use `strsplit()` to split on spaces and finally grab the value. I can write a function for this, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel here, so if anyone knows of a built-in argument or existing function I would be much obliged.

Answer (score 2):

With `lavInspect()` and `lavTech()` you can extract information from fitted `lavaan` objects. You can for example extract the chisquare value using:

```
  x<-lavInspect(model, "fit")
  x["chisq"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lavInspect(model, "test")$standard$stat.group
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it